# Gravity Scale 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

В компоненте Rigidbody2D есть такой параметр как Gravity Scale каким образом он влияет на глобальный компонент гравитации? 
Т. е. если вектор по x Physics2D.gravity = - 10 объект на котором Rb2D c Gravity Scale 2 будет воспринимать  Physics2D.gravity как - 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идем в [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html):

> **The degree to which this object is affected by gravity**.
>
> In 2D physics, the gravity is a global setting in the Physics2D class
>   but you can also **control the proportion of that gravity applied to
>   each object individually using gravityScale**. For example, it may be
>   easier to implement a flying character by turning off its gravity
>   rather than simulating the forces that keep it aloft.

---

TL;DR

Да, конечная гравитация, воздействующая на объект: `GlobalGravity * gravityScale`